# SSL certificate for EC2 instance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, server, backend

Iv'e launch an EC2 instance in AWS and ran NODE app on port 3000.
Making requests to it from postman works fine
<ec2_path>.com:3000/api/.. works as expected.
Problem start when I try attaching a ssl certificate to it.
So here are the steps:

1. Created hosted zone in Route53
2. Created application load balancer and added listener on port 443 (HTTPS)
3. Created target group and attached the ec2 instance with port 3000
4. Generated SSL cert in ssl certificate manager on aws.
5. Created A record alias to ALB in the hosted zone on route53.

From what I understand, the ssl domain now attach to alb which listens on port 443 so essentially https://custom-domain ---> load-balancer--> target group ec2 (port 3000) --> my running server.

What happens in reality is postman loads forever and alb monitoring doesnt show requests

- security group on ec2 allows ports 3000,80,8080,443 from everywhere (3000 is custom TCP)
- security group on ALB allows traffic from anywhere on all ports.

Answer (score 0):

The ALB was adding a default security group which was not enough.
Ive added my own custom security group and it works!